# How can I set a cap for FPS in an Eclipse IDE project?

Tags: java, eclipse, game-development, frame-rate

While following a tutorial for game development in Java (Guide is by Kaarin Gaming, source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFS9Whsoecc&list=PL4rzdwizLaxYmltJQRjq18a9gsSyEQQ-0&index=8 ), I ran into an error on limiting my FPS count. His code looks mostly similar to my code other than for a few lines,

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        
        updateRectangle();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect((int)xDelta, (int)yDelta, 50, 50);
        
        // basic FPS counter
                frames++;
                if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastCheck >= 1000) {
                    lastCheck = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                    frames = 0;
                    
                }
                repaint();
    }
```

While the repaint(); is there, the game runs at 2300 FPS, which is way too high. So what he does to fix it is to add some code (of which I've already added) and then remove the repaint();. However, when I do it, the game wont run and the FPS will stay at a static 1.

I've tried changing the intervals between frames refreshing, moving the repaint(); around to different parts of the code that might need it/don't have it yet, and I've watched the video again to find a mistake but I haven't found anything.

Something else to note, I'm new to programming. So if you do have an answer, please explain why so I can understand better, Thank you.

Comment: if you are 'new to programming', you should start at the beginning, not trying to create a complex application, specially not if it uses tools and frameworks you don't understand. You show way too little information for us to go on (and we're definitely not going through that link), put all relevant information needed to debug in the question itself, but seriously, familiarize yourself with the tools and language before taking on big projects

Answer (score 0):

I don't think learning coding while making a game is inherently bad. You encounter real-world problems that require thinking and good problem solving. I assume your update routine is also called 2300 times per second. If it records when it last executed, then if that time is less than 1000ms divided by desired-frame-rate, you should just return from the function.

What you have is a function that increments `frames` counter. And when the `System.currentTimeMillis() - lastCheck >= 1000` updates `lastCheck` time and resets the counter for `frames`.

What seems wrong here is where `repaint()` is located. It's being called each time `paintComponent` is called, rather than each time you would wish to permit an actual `repaint()`.

Placing the repaint in to the if-statement won't work either. That is simply waiting 1000ms (1 second) before outputting the FPS rate.

You also lack the function I describe in my opening statements.

You need to:

- add a variable that stores the time when the last repaint was called
- add some conditional logic similar to the FPS if-statement to deduce when enough time has passed and you should actually call repaint

I've not put a running sample together, but I think the following is what you need, albeit it might need a tweak because I haven't tested it.

```
// class member fields
long lastRepaintTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long desiredMaxFrameRate = 30;
long frameRateInterval = 1000 / desiredMaxFrameRate;


public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
    // only do UI activity if the frameRateInterval has elapsed
    if (now - lastRepaintTime >= frameRateInterval)
    {
        frames++;   // only count frames we actually render
        updateRectangle();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect((int)xDelta, (int)yDelta, 50, 50);

        // basic FPS counter - check if it's been 1000+ms since we last output the frame count
        if(now - lastCheck >= 1000) {
            lastCheck = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
            frames = 0;
        }
        repaint();                                    // perform the actual repaint/rendering
        lastRepaintTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // update the lastRepaintTime
    }
}
```

EDIT: it isn't clear how you end up with the FPS always being 1 unless you somehow only call `paintComponent` each second. If you're trying to use `lastCheck` in unposted code to limit how often you call `paintComponent` you need to realize that `lastCheck` should only be used for when you wish to output the FPS rate, not for rate-limiting when you wish to update the screen.